# cant get monitor mode "Aircrack-ng" in my ubuntu 17.10

Tags: network-monitoring, aircrack-ng

here is problem.there isn't monitor mode.so i can't use **aircrack-ng** 
please help me!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In terminal use the following commands :

```
sudo airmon-ng check
airmon-ng check kill
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

Don't forget to restart the network manager :

```
service network-manager start
```